# Adding information from a form to UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, forms, uitableview, swift4

I am trying to add information from a pop up form into a table. See the form picture below. So when the user enters save I want the artist to be a header and the album, cost etc. to populate as cells within that header. Any ideas, I'm honestly totally lost. I'm using xCode and Swift 4, Thanks!

[Pop-Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf3dG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without specific code it is hard to provide specific solution.

Here is the generic solution.

List view controller with UITableView:
* Provides array with list of items
* Allows pop-up to create (or edit item).

May look like this:

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
  @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
  // Assume VinylDataModel is a struct or simple class to hold the named fields
  var items = [VinylDataModel]()
  // Create outlets for the form labels: form_field1... form_fieldN
  ...

  @IBAction func createPressed() {
    self.someForm.isHidden = false
  }

  @IBAction func savePressed() {
    self.someForm.isHidden = true

    //Add the item to the array by pulling field from the UITextField into our struct
    items.append(VinylDataModel(field1: form_field1.text, ... fieldN: form_fieldN.text)
    tableView.reloadData()
  }

//Assume you implement the standard methods of UITableViewDataSource using the array 'items'
}
```

The edit view allows entry, and when it is finished must provide a callback to the list of items. If this is the same view controller, you can map the touchUpInside pressed of the 'save' button.

Comment: Thank you! I just needed a second opinion. This helps loads.